# Inject class into plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin, dependency-injection, construct

I created an plugin for `afterGetProductPriceHtml()` and it works so far. My di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
      <plugin name="add_streichpreis" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Streichpreis" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And the plugin:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

class Streichpreis
{
    public function afterGetProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product
    ) {
        $streichpreistyp=$_product->getAttributeText('streichpreistyp');
        $basePrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
        $regularPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
        $specialPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();

        $out="";
        if ($streichpreistyp!="" && $specialPrice < $regularPrice) {

            $displayregular = number_format($regularPrice, 2, ',', '.')." €";
            $streichpreistyp='<span class="streichpreistyp">'.$streichpreistyp.'</span>';
            $displayregular='<span class="streichpreis"><span class="price">'.$displayregular.'</span><span>';
            $percent=(($regularPrice - $specialPrice) / $regularPrice) * 100;
            $percent=round($percent);
            $percent='<span class="percent-of">-'.$percent.'</span>';
            $out=$streichpreistyp.$displayregular.$percent;
        }
        return $result.$out;
    }
}
```

The part, that I am not really proud of is this:

```
$displayregular = number_format($regularPrice, 2, ',', '.')." €";
```

How can I incect another class into the plugin?
To get the formatted price, I need to use

`\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface`

to format the price, but I am not able to add a __construct function into the plugin. What is the correct way to use another class in a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

class Streichpreis {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency) {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;

    }
    public function afterGetProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product
    ) {
        $streichpreistyp = $_product->getAttributeText('streichpreistyp');
        $basePrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
        $regularPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
        $specialPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();

        $out = "";
        if ($streichpreistyp != "" && $specialPrice < $regularPrice) {

            $displayregular = number_format($regularPrice, 2, ',', '.') . " €";
            $streichpreistyp = '<span class="streichpreistyp">' . $streichpreistyp . '</span>';
            $displayregular = '<span class="streichpreis"><span class="price">' . $displayregular . '</span><span>';
            $percent = (($regularPrice - $specialPrice) / $regularPrice) * 100;
            $percent = round($percent);
            $percent = '<span class="percent-of">-' . $percent . '</span>';
            $out = $streichpreistyp . $displayregular . $percent;
        }
        return $result . $out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

class Streichpreis
{
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct( $context, $data );
    }

    public function afterGetProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product
    ) {
        $streichpreistyp=$_product->getAttributeText('streichpreistyp');
        $basePrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
        $regularPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
        $specialPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();

        $out="";
        if ($streichpreistyp!="" && $specialPrice < $regularPrice) {

            $displayregular = number_format($regularPrice, 2, ',', '.')." €";
            $streichpreistyp='<span class="streichpreistyp">'.$streichpreistyp.'</span>';
            $displayregular='<span class="streichpreis"><span class="price">'.$displayregular.'</span><span>';
            $percent=(($regularPrice - $specialPrice) / $regularPrice) * 100;
            $percent=round($percent);
            $percent='<span class="percent-of">-'.$percent.'</span>';
            $out=$streichpreistyp.$displayregular.$percent;
        }
        return $result.$out;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt test your answer, but the answer of rakesh-varma worked for me.

Comment: kindly up-vote my answer